# What is $\mathbb FG$ for $\mathbb F$ a field and $G$ a finite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

I have encountered the notation $\mathbb FG$ for $\mathbb F$ a field and $G$ a finite group, but I don't know what this stands for. I am to show that the center of $R=\mathbb FG$ is a linear subspace of $R$ and prove its dimension is equal to the number of conjugacy classes in $G$.

What is $\mathbb FG$?

Comment: As Orat says it's the group ring (really it's a Hopf algebra), it's also sometimes written $\mathbb{F}[G]$.

Answer (score 4):

It's what is frequently called a group algebra.  Basically, it is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ with the basis being elements of the group (treated as formal symbols).  So if your group was $\{e, a, a^{2}\}$ (with $a^{3} = e$), then 
$$\mathbb{F}G = \{ c_{1}\cdot e +c_{2} \cdot a + c_{3} \cdot a^{2} \ : \ c_{i} \in \mathbb{F}\}.$$
In addition to being a vector space, you have a multiplication of vectors that uses the group multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

It stands for [group ring](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Group_ring) which appears in group representation theory.